# zaproxy - API scan - missing c in config

Tags: zap

I run the following command: `docker run -v /etc/hosts:/etc/hosts -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk:rw -t owasp/zap2docker-weekly zap-api-scan.py -t api.yaml -f openapi -r zap_report.html -config replacer.full_list\(0\).description=auth1 -config replacer.full_list\(0\).enabled=true -config replacer.full_list\(0\).matchtype=REQ_HEADER -config replacer.full_list\(0\).matchstr=X-XXXXX-APIkey -config replacer.full_list\(0\).regex=false -config replacer.full_list\(0\).replacement=123456789`

But got the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/zap/zap-api-scan.py", line 539, in
>
> File "/zap/zap-api-scan.py", line 246, in main
>       with open(base_dir + config_file) as f:
>   IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/zap/wrk/onfig'

How is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in how you pass parameters to the python script. The python script parse  the `-config` as `-c onfig`, and trying to read configuration from the file `onfig`. You should pass zap params using the following format: `-z "-config aaa=bbb -config ccc=ddd"'`